# Character Comparison

Tags: java

I'm currently doing an online course, however it doesn't seem to enjoy this method: `Character.isWhiteSpace(c)`

What other methods are there that can answer the below question?

Assume that `c` is a char variable has been declared and already given a value. Write an expression whose value is true if and only if `x` is what is called a whitespace character (that is a space or a tab or a newline-- none of which result in ink being printed on paper).

Comment: I'm doing a rather annoying online course kind of thing, and it asks for a specific expression. I thought it was Character.isWhiteSpace(c) however that wasn't the answer unfortunately...

Comment: Wow...the answer was indeed:

c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n'||c=='\r'

I would've just used the method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to/can't use libraries

```
c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n'||c=='\r'
```

note that `\r` is a carriage return it's part of the windows `\r\n` combination (and used commonly in network protocols)

Answer (score 4):

The Character class has the function `Character.isWhitespace(char)`.  See the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

There is a java API for this: [`Character.isWhiteSpace(c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)